# Android listview, view cell will only update once

Tags: android, listview, view, adapter

I have a listview with custom array adapter, the view allows the user to change a variable up and down with some plus and minus buttons I implemented

now the problem is that the plus/minus buttons will change the view ONCE, but after that time it won't update until the view is refreshed a different way.  like using an `listview.notifydatasetchanged()` in an external operation.

when it updates, it shows that the plus/minus buttons WERE registering clicks and updating the variable, because on update of the data set it immediately puts the correct variable in the view

why isn't the individual view updating on its own?

```
  private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    TextView quantity;
    int i;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_scanneditems, null);
        }

            final Item allItems = items.get(position);




        //declare all parts of the cell
        TextView product = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        quantity = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNum);
        TextView category = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        TextView price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.productCost);

        product.setText(allItems.product);
        category.setText(allItems.category);
        price.setText("$" + allItems.price);
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(allItems.quantity)); //might want to do ceiling and floor functions here, IF weight not present

        //set properties within on click listeners
        //items.set(position, allItems.quantity);

        ImageView selectLeft = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.selectleft_list);
        ImageView selectRight = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.selectright_list);

        CheckBox itemCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);        

        itemCheckBox.setChecked(selectallListener);

        itemCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked==false && selectallListener==true)
                {
                    selectallListener=false;

                    CheckBox selectAll = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
                    selectAll.setChecked(false);
                }
            }

        });


        selectLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(allItems.quantity > 0) //i greater than 0, decrement -1
                {
                    allItems.setQuantity(allItems.quantity-1);
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(allItems.quantity));
                }
                else //i less or equal to 0
                {

                    allItems.setQuantity(0);
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(allItems.quantity));

                    //turn icon into an X here an if it is X delete the item

                }

            }//onclick

        });//selectleft listener

        selectRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                allItems.setQuantity(allItems.quantity+1);
                quantity.setText(String.valueOf(allItems.quantity));

            }//onclick

        });//selectRight listener

        //do I need viewholder here?

        //set listeners


        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quantity variable could be unrelated to the current view in which clicks happens. Now it always is the TextView created/processed in last getView call.

I think must be like allItems variable.
in getView function

final TextView quantity =…

Comment: Instead of class variable use local/function variable. Just like allItems (what a misleading name) variable.


...
//declare all parts of the cell
        TextView product = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        final TextView quantity = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNum);

...