# Add quantity to a checkbox item in an Android ListView

Tags: android

I have a List with Checkboxes and i want to every item on the List to add a quantity field, so the user can enter a value like 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Ok very nice case. Have you tried anything?

Comment: i have found this image http://www.grocerygadgets.com/Images/GG%20QG%20Android/ChangingQty.png
and as far i can remember it was something that was in the graphical layout of the xml files. Now i guess the only solution is to add a textfield that accepts only numbers?

Comment: This code will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109257/android-listview-view-cell-will-only-update-once

Comment: If my comment was helpful for you, I added it as answer. Please consider telling what you need to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this similar question:

[Android listview, view cell will only update once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109257/android-listview-view-cell-will-only-update-once)

This user seems to have the same idea than you, you don't have the xml layout, but it's not easy to write, isn't it?